# Cant get text from the PyQT5 text field

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

Can't understand why I'm getting the empty string from the text field, here is my code:

```
class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow, test.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        super().setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.click)

    def click(self):
        text = self.plainTextEdit.toPlainText()
        print('Text: ' + str(text))
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QMainWindow()
    mainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    mainWindow.setupUi(window)
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

https://pastebin.com/gpDSysL2

and the generated by QT Designer .py file:

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.plainTextEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 260, 104, 71))
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(270, 350, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
```

when im clicking on the button it printing the empy string
here is the screenshot of the issue im getting [>>> Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3zmz.png)

will be very appreciated for you any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in double calling setupUI() method:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = QMainWindow()
    mainWindow = MyMainWindow()
    # mainWindow.setupUi(window)  <<< HERE WAS THE PROBLEM, JUST DELETEd THIS LINE AND THATS ALL
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

maybe somebody will have same issue